# Read XML Spread Sheet 2003 by column in C#

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I need to read a XML Spread Sheet 2003 in a project and I have a problem with columns.

This example show you have king of template my data are :

```
Name Of | FirstName | SecondName | ... | ... 

Monday  |     1     |     2      |   3 |   2 

Tuesday |     0     |     1      |   1 |   ?

Wednesday |   2     |     ?      |   ? |   ?
```

I need to extract every data in each columns and the problem is here : C# read this XML Spread Sheet row by row only and with this example I don't know how I can have exactly every data for each column. Moreover I can't know in advance the data.

Here is the beginning of my code

```
var queryPeriodSheet = from worksheet in data.Descendants(ss + "Worksheet")
                               where worksheet.Attribute(ss + "Name").Value == "sheet1"
                               select worksheet;

var rows = from row in queryPeriodSheet.Descendants(ss + "Row")
select row;
```

...

I need your help,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the ss:Index attribute in each cell element in each row since there are no XML elements for empty cells.

I use the following code to find text in a specific cell in a row:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rowElement"></param>
    /// <param name="cellIndex">0-based cell index.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetCellData(XmlElement rowElement, int cellIndex)
    {
        XmlNodeList cellElements = rowElement.SelectNodes("ss:Cell", xmlnsManager);
        if (cellElements != null)
        {
            int elementIndex = 0;

            foreach (XmlElement cellElement in cellElements)
            {
                // Special case: cells can be skipped. If so, there is a ss:Index attribute that contains the 1-based index of the cell.
                if (cellElement.HasAttribute("ss:Index"))
                {
                    elementIndex = Convert.ToInt32(cellElement.GetAttribute("ss:Index")) - 1;
                }

                // If cell has been skipped.
                if (cellIndex < elementIndex)
                    return null;

                if (cellIndex == elementIndex)
                    return cellElement.InnerText.Trim();

                elementIndex++;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```